# getting varriable from service to the controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

im trying to get a varriable from this service but i can't manage to do this. i've looked online and got nothing.service:

```
    .factory('localStorageService', function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.go = function(task) {
        var dataReceiver = localStorage.getItem('taskData');
        var array = [];
        var newArray = array.push({"title" : task});

        if(dataReceiver === null) {
            localStorage.setItem("taskData", JSON.stringify(array));

            dataReceiver = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('taskData'));
            console.log(dataReceiver);
        }
        else {
            array = JSON.parse(dataReceiver);
            var newArray2 = array.push({"title" : task});
            localStorage.setItem("taskData", JSON.stringify(array));

            dataReceiver = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('taskData'));

            for(var i = 0; i < newArray2; i++) {
                console.log(dataReceiver[i].title);
            }   
        }

        return dataReceiver;
    }
})
```

controller:

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, PlaylistService, localStorageService) {

console.log(localStorageService.go());
```

})

it says it cannot read property go of undefined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24483115/1225190

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare with module the factory belongs to, that's why localStorageService is undefined in your controller. And yes, you also shouldn't be appending go to rootScope. Your factory should look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).factory('localStorageService', function($rootScope){

this.go = function(task) {
    var dataReceiver = localStorage.getItem('taskData');
    var array = [];
    var newArray = array.push({"title" : task});

    if(dataReceiver === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("taskData", JSON.stringify(array));

        dataReceiver = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('taskData'));
        console.log(dataReceiver);
    }
    else {
        array = JSON.parse(dataReceiver);
        var newArray2 = array.push({"title" : task});
        localStorage.setItem("taskData", JSON.stringify(array));

        dataReceiver = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('taskData'));

        for(var i = 0; i < newArray2; i++) {
            console.log(dataReceiver[i].title);
        }   
    }

    return dataReceiver;
};

return this;
```

});

By returning the factory object it and all of it's methods are then available when injected into your controller.

Comment: my service.js file looks like this:angular.module('Todo.services', [])
 .factory('PlaylistService', function(){}.factory

Comment: i also have a service above this currect service and its still working so i dont think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you put the method 'go' on the rootscope and not on the factory.

Your factory is returning the object dataReceiver which does not have a method 'go'.

Put the 'go' method on the object that is being returned from the factory and you will be able to get it.

Here is a basic plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wbCedJx8BJ4nOvuNWQc7

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, myFactory) {

    $scope.greetings = myFactory.go();

});

app.factory('myFactory', function () {

  this.go = function () {
    return 'hello from factory';
  };

  return this;
});
```

Markup:

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <h1>Greetings: {{ greetings }}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i couldn't understand what you meant. could you show me an example?

Comment: I added some code, you need to return an object from your factory.  that object that is returned will be the one you are calling when you use the injected service in a controller.  So in the code sample I set the method 'go' to this and returned this.

Comment: copied that inside of my factory and the controller can't find it, the code inside the controller: console.log(localStorageService.go()); when i simply remove this line, the service itself isn't not working, unlike before.

Comment: I've added a basic plunkr for the factory use case for factories.  Hope it helps.

Comment: i have no idea what im doing wrong... take a look at this fiddlejs:http://jsfiddle.net/NqSW9/ maybe you'll find it

Answer (score 0):

Service

```
app.factory('localStorageService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        go: function() {
            //do your stuff here
            var dataReceiver = localStorage.getItem('taskData');
            var array = [];
            var newArray = array.push({"title" : task});

            if(dataReceiver === null) {
                localStorage.setItem("taskData", JSON.stringify(array));

                dataReceiver = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('taskData'));
                console.log(dataReceiver);
            }
            else {
                array = JSON.parse(dataReceiver);
                var newArray2 = array.push({"title" : task});
                localStorage.setItem("taskData", JSON.stringify(array));

                dataReceiver = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('taskData'));

                for(var i = 0; i < newArray2; i++) {
                    console.log(dataReceiver[i].title);
                }   
            }

            return dataReceiver;
        }
    }
}]);
```

controller

```
app.controller('PlaylistsCtrl',
    function PlaylistsCtrl($scope, PlaylistService, localStorageService) {
        console.log(localStorageService.go())
    }
)
```

Comment: this returns: undefined is not a function

Comment: i added "task" to the go function, and it partially worked. the controller is doing what it suppose to do but the service is doing nothing, unlike before.